# Cannot Actvate Setup assistant in MacOS Catalina after Migration Crash

Tags: catalina, crash, migration, setup-assistant

I bought a new Macbook Air 2018 with macOS Catalina.  I wanted to transfer my stuff from my old computer so I tried to use Migration Assistant.  It crashed in the middle of the process.

Now my main user is "corrupted".  I cannot login because it crashes and reboots every time I try to access.

I tried Activate Setup assistant in recovery mode but I'm still getting the message `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/var/db/.AppleSetupDone no such file or directory`.

What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'd nuke & pave from Internet Recovery & just start over.